# Write in a DocBlock programmaticaly Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, docblocks

I have a Simulink model with a DocBlock inside and i would like to create a script to write inside this DocBlock.
I already have this code :

```
A = find_system('MyModel', 'BlockType', 'SubSystem', 'Mask', 'on', 'MaskType', 'DocBlock');
B = get_param(A, 'UserData');
B = cell2mat(B);
B.content = 'Test';
disp(B.content);
set_param(string(A), 'UserData', B.content);
```

The problem is after i run the script if i double click on the DocBlock the data doesn't change i don't know why. Do someone know how to change the content of a DocBlock ?

Edit : I modify a little bit the set_param line and add a get_param line to verify that the change is happening :

```
set_param(Hndle, 'UserData', B);
C = get_param(Hndle, 'UserData');
```

And when i display C, it actually display the change but when i double click on the DocBlock it doesn't change the data i really don't understand

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this (thanks to someone in the mathworks forum) :

```
set_param(Hndle, 'UserData', B,'UserDataPersistent','On');
```

Just add `'UserDataPersistent','On'` in the set_param line.